# Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1 address=0xe07eca10)

Tags: iphone, exception, exc-bad-access

I have a problem with a UIView. This is the code:

```
@property ( unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *formView;


- (IBAction)createNewProfile:(id)sender {
   [self loadDialogForm];
}

-(void) loadDialogForm{
    NSLog(@"load form");
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake( frame.origin.x +    ceil(frame.size.width/2),frame.origin.y + ceil(frame.size.height/2));
    CGFloat width = floor(1 * frame.size.width) - OFFSET * 2;
    CGFloat height = floor(1 * frame.size.height) - OFFSET * 2;

    _formView.frame=CGRectMake(OFFSET, OFFSET, width, height); //here the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xe07eca10)
    _formView.center=center;

    [self.view addSubview:_formView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(initialDelayEnded) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

by a NSLog the frame of _formView is x= 0, y=0, width=300, height=390. Why this error?

Comment: check that _formView is not nil

Comment: Put the line that's failing inside a @try/@catch section and log the exception (and its `callStackSymbols`) to get a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: try to use CGRect frame = [self.view frame];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

@property ( nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *formView;

instead of

@property ( unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *formView;

Comment: I'm using ARC that not want retain.

Comment: @ConicaDegenere Yes you do - or actually you want `strong` which is a synonym for `retain`.  As you have it, your view can be released while you still have a reference to it - that's what `unsafe_unretained` does (and the reason why unsafe is in there, because it isn't safe.